# Font suddenly changes - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Everytime I paste an UTF-8/Ascii Charachter, the Font changes from normal to a larger one.

I am pasting it in the normal Editor in a .java File. Is there any way to set it back?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: where do you paste it?

Comment: really unclear what you are asking plus what are you copying, where from and where to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

`Windows->Preferences`

`General->Appearence->Colors and Fonts`

Press "Restore Defaults"